# How to get the Gross Sales from the Square Order API?

Tags: square

**Qn1) I have tried getting the gross sales from the Order API. However, I could only be able to get each lineitem gross value concatenating with one and another ...**

[Gross value that is concatenating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFfNo.png)

**Qn2) I tried to echo all the item name, qty and etc to insert it into my database although it works but I am getting an error message shown below**

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2M5R.png)

**Here is my code: (Have replaced the access token and the location_id to 'XXXX')**

```
<html>
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use Square\SquareClient;
use Square\Environment;

$client = new SquareClient([
    'accessToken' => 'XXXX',
    'environment' => Environment::PRODUCTION,
]);

$location_ids = ['XXXX'];
$created_at = new \Square\Models\TimeRange();
$created_at->setStartAt('2021-05-17T00:00:00+08:00');
$created_at->setEndAt('2021-05-17T23:59:59+08:00'); 

$date_time_filter = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersDateTimeFilter();
$date_time_filter->setCreatedAt($created_at);

$filter = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersFilter();
$filter->setDateTimeFilter($date_time_filter);

$sort = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersSort('CREATED_AT');
$sort->setSortOrder('DESC');

$query = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersQuery();
$query->setFilter($filter);
$query->setSort($sort);

$body = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersRequest();
$body->setLocationIds($location_ids);
$body->setQuery($query);
$body->setLimit(10000);
$body->setReturnEntries(false);

$api_response = $client->getOrdersApi()->searchOrders($body);

if ($api_response->isSuccess()) {
    $result = $api_response->getResult();
    $orders = $result->getOrders();
    
    foreach($orders as $x => $val) {
            $lineItems = $result->getOrders()[$x]->getLineItems();
        $orderid = $result->getOrders()[$x]->getId();
    
        foreach($lineItems as $q => $val2){
            $lineItemsID = $lineItems[$q]->getUid();
            $itemName = $lineItems[$q]->getName();
            $itemQty = $lineItems[$q]->getQuantity();
            $catalogObjID = $lineItems[$q]->getCatalogobjectid();
            $grossSales[] = $lineItems[$q]->getGrossSalesMoney()->getAmount();

            echo (array_sum($grossSales)/100); //Qn1

            echo($orderid. "   ". $lineItemsID ."   ".$catalogObjID."   ".$itemName ."  ".$itemQty." <br/>"); //Qn2
            }   
        }
} 

else 
{
    $errors = $api_response->getErrors();
}

?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use Square\SquareClient;
use Square\Environment;

$client = new SquareClient([
    'accessToken' => 'XXXX',
    'environment' => Environment::PRODUCTION,
]);

$location_ids = ['XXXX'];
$created_at = new \Square\Models\TimeRange();
$created_at->setStartAt('2021-05-17T00:00:00+08:00');
$created_at->setEndAt('2021-05-17T23:59:59+08:00'); 

$date_time_filter = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersDateTimeFilter();
$date_time_filter->setCreatedAt($created_at);

$filter = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersFilter();
$filter->setDateTimeFilter($date_time_filter);

$sort = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersSort('CREATED_AT');
$sort->setSortOrder('DESC');

$query = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersQuery();
$query->setFilter($filter);
$query->setSort($sort);

$body = new \Square\Models\SearchOrdersRequest();
$body->setLocationIds($location_ids);
$body->setQuery($query);
$body->setLimit(10000);
$body->setReturnEntries(false);

$api_response = $client->getOrdersApi()->searchOrders($body);

if ($api_response->isSuccess()) {
    $result = $api_response->getResult();
    $orders = $result->getOrders();

    $grossSales = array();
    
    if (is_array($orders) || is_object($orders)) {
    foreach($orders as $x => $val) {
        $lineItems = $result->getOrders()[$x]->getLineItems();
        $orderid = $result->getOrders()[$x]->getId();
        
        if (is_array($lineItems) || is_object($lineItems)){
        foreach($lineItems as $q => $val2){
            $lineItemsID = $lineItems[$q]->getUid();
            $itemName = $lineItems[$q]->getName();
            $itemQty = $lineItems[$q]->getQuantity();
            $catalogObjID = $lineItems[$q]->getCatalogobjectid();
            $grossSales[] = $lineItems[$q]->getGrossSalesMoney()->getAmount();
            }
          }   
        }
     }
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($grossSales as $key=>$value)
    {
      $sum+= $value;
    }
    echo ($sum/100);
} 

else 
{
    $errors = $api_response->getErrors();
}

?>
</html>
```